# mysql IF EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have this table

```
UMS

id_attribute    value   order
1                MB      1
1                Gb      2
1                TB      3
...
```

and this table

```
ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
id    id_attribute          value  name     ums
 1         1                 50     hdd     GB
 2         1                 100    hdd     TB
 3         2                 15.00  price   NULL
```

and i want to select from ATTRIBUTE_VALUE where id_attribute=1 and if exist (UMS.value=ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.ums) then order by UMS.order end if  group by ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.value

example for output :

```
50 GB
100 Tb

   and must to appear 
    15.00   !!! here is the problem because in my UMS table i don't have UMS for price

    but it doesn't appear
```

Comment: What should *do something* be? Something that should be executed with SQL or something in PHP? (anyway, `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM y where 1=1 )` will always evaluate to `true` )

Comment: I want something that should be executed with PHP, because I have this:

select * from y where 1='$value'

and if is true then order by name
else order by price

or something like this

Comment: @cosy: This does not really clarify the question. Could you please edit your question and provide a decent explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: and if not exists not order by UMS.order

Comment: Are you sure you want to group by ATTRIBUTE_VALUE and not order by it?

Comment: Yes i am sure because i will have 100 product width hdd 50 GB, for example

Comment: @cosy: I think the group by won't do what you expect. Could you show us what output you expect for the above input? Perhaps add a few more example rows in your test data too.

Comment: @cosy: So you only want to select the value and UMS columns? You don't want the id or name? And where you say 'here is the problem', what exactly is the problem? Is that result that you posted what you want to get? Or is it the wrong result? If it's the wrong result, then what should the correct result be?

Comment: The problem is that after the query run the price doesn't appear

Comment: @cosy: If you look at my updated answer you can see that price is returned, but also there are many other columns that don't exist in your output. I'm not entirely sure why you want the group by. I'm also not sure why "price" should come sorted after "GB" or "TB".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update after you clarified your question - Try something like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUE T1
LEFT JOIN UMS T2
ON T1.id_attribute = T2.id_attribute AND T1.ums = T2.value
ORDER BY T2.order, T1.value
```

But note that this will fail if T1.value is greater than 1000. It might be better to convert all units to the same type before ordering them.

Result of query:

```
id  id_attribute  value  name    ums
3   2             15.00  price     
1   1             50     hdd     GB
2   1             100    hdd     TB
```

Comment: But how can I do something like this?

Comment: The problem is, in this table named attribute_value I will have attribute that will did not appear in UMS table. And in this case my selection stoped

Comment: Thanks! I resolve my problem, on my own. Anyway you got the best answer!

Comment: And for your curiosity this is the website link, in the right i have the filter http://www.demo.ewstudio.ro/agatatori/compact-mirror sorry but it is not in english

Answer (score 0):

You can make a conditional order by in mysql, like this, for example:

```
user 
id    name
```

---

```
select *
from user 
order by (case when id <5 then id else name end)
```

However, you've got two tables, you need yo join them, I'm still not sure if you can get what you need this way.
Also, you can't order with DESC on one branch and ASC on another.

Answer (score 0):

Finlay I have get my own answer:

this is the code:

```
$nr_ordine=0;
$virgula="";
$ordine="valoare";
$ordine2="FIELD(unitate_masura,";
$sql_ums=mysql_query("select * from atribute_masura where id_atribut='".$exe_atribut['id']."' order by ordine asc");
while($exe_ums=mysql_fetch_array($sql_ums))
{
$nr_ordine++;
if($nr_ordine>1)
{
$virgula=",";
};


$ordine2.=$virgula."'".$exe_ums['valoare']."'";
};
$ordine2.=")";
if($ordine2!="FIELD(unitate_masura,)")
{
$ordine=$ordine2;
};


$s_q0=mysql_query("select * from atribute_cautare where id_atribut='".$exe_atribut['id']."' group by valoare order by $ordine asc") or die (mysql_error());        
while($s_q=mysql_fetch_array($s_q0))
{

...
};
```

The names not correspond with my question but this is the idea **order by FIELD (ums,'kb','mb','gb','tb')**